# Best option to run Ubuntu? From partition? USB? or virtual box?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi

I have a new laptop that secure boot enabled with UEFI firmware. The main use would be for previewing media in a read only environment and preforming dd imaging of said media. What would be the benefits of a partition installation vs a persistent USB installation on a 3.0 USB? 
Does it matter which partition is used (ie: a volume that I shrink to add ubnuntu or an ssd drive added to install ubuntu.)
Would a persistent USB installation be bootable with a secure boot environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: This seems to be a "non question" - of course the fastest way to use Ubuntu (or any OS) would be from a dedicated drive/partition.

Comment: you are asking for opinion, not solution.

Comment: Ubuntu will run best from the fastest medium you have. Benchmark them if you're not sure. If you have other issues (partitioning, data sharing, etc) that's between you and your gods. UEFI and secure boot are both fine on newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @markkirby edit made as suggested.

Comment: :)  good edit, you have my reopen vote. You have 3 out of 5 votes now, I think this will be reopened soon.

Answer (score 1):

This heavily depends on what you are planning to do on Ubuntu.

**Option 1: LiveUSB**
I would recommend this for trying Ubuntu, but not for a permanent System, because it will not have a very good performance.

**Option 2: Virtual Machine**
This may be a good solution, if you want to keep your current OS (Windows?) as main OS and use Ubuntu from time to time for specific tasks.

**Option 3: Complete Installation**
I would recommend this option, if you want to use Ubuntu as your main OS. You can decide for a dual boot configuration, if you want to keep your current OS. Regarding the question, whether to use partitions or two drives: This is also dependent of the hardware you have. Normally installing Ubuntu in a separate partition works fine. But you should consider using a different drive, if it is very small.